# VueJS detect if string contains words

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm looking to detect whether or not a string has **any** word.

```
"DD8BC606-E0C0-41A2-8E7E-FCB2A1D66D76.jpeg" // false
"Image of Logo JPG" // true
```

I'd imagine there needs to be some sort of reference to the English dictionary on what constitutes a word, but in my scenario it could be in any language.

I've tried to split the string into an array of words and check the word length for non absurd lengths (though some words especially in German are absurdly long).

```
string_to_array = function (str) {
     return str.trim().split(" ");
};
```

In the same vain, I tried count how many words there are in the array and require at least 2 (which would be a strong indicator that the string has been typed by a human - i.e. a word), but this invalidates one word strings (although this isn't a stringent requirement).

What's the fastest ad-hoc way to make sure that there is at least a word in a string?

Comment: What did you done so far? Please add it in the question.

Comment: @VaritJPatel - Updated

I guess I'm stuck on the more abstract side of how to do it. I've tried to check that each given word (by converting the string to array of words) isn't longer than a given length, and I've also tried looking for spaces within a string (though this would invalidate one word strings). I'm trying to see if there's a better method that I missed.

Comment: Basically It is about the approach than the method. So if your approach is posted and then better approach would be provided.

Comment: @VaritJPatel sure thing - updated :)

Comment: Just find whitespaces in the string, i.e. `\w`?

Comment: @Terry yeah that was an initial thought but it wouldn't pass single word strings that don't have a whitespace

Comment: Feels like an XY problem: why do you want to enforce words? And some valid words can contain numbers, too, e.g. "2-by-2" (which contains numerals, dashes, alphabets, and no whitespaces)

Comment: @Terry Good question - basically I have a file input where the filename gets populated by the actual filename of the file (as stored on the users device). Some people are good with naming their files (locally) and the names are descriptive, others just don't care and use the default generated strings (as in the example). I'd like to force users to write descriptive titles for their files, while still not forcing people that name their files correctly to have to retype said filename titles on the upload screen.

Comment: This is purely opinion: but people should be able to name their files however they want. The naming of the file does not affect how it is accessed or read anyway. There is no reason to enforce an arbitrary requirement like that.

Comment: @Terry The idea to enforce it is not per-se for the actual filename (as stored in cloud storage) but for the filename that gets stored in the DB, which is then used for search operations. Both are the same in this case.

Comment: If they chose to use a bad file name, then the onus is on them if they can't find the file ;)

Comment: @Terry oh my do I want to live in your utopia :D If I said that to my customers I'd probably be renamed to a random string and forgotten just like they forget where their files are when they don't name them correctly and then can't search for them :P

Joking aside - you may be right, it might be time to fire up some automatic (maybe even AI based) tagging system for the files...

Or maybe just disable the initial autofill altogether and have everyone suffer because of a few apples that don't name their stuff

Comment: 1) the problem is: what you mean by "word", (the prefix "any" is secondary ...). It is not a deterministic computer problem .. or it is AI.  2) 
you're talking about a scenario, but what is it? what is the final goal ?

Comment: @Eric the final goal is to discard random / non-descriptive strings (at least a majority anyway). I figured this might be something for AI, but then we get into languages...